# How can I use the standard JSON formatter from an action of my controller in an ASP.NET MVC 5.1 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, formatter, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In one of the actions of in my controller I need to serialize an object to JSON I wish I could use the standard JSON formatter that is shipped with ASP.NET MVC 5.1. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So are you having any issues with using `return Json(obj,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`? Here is a good article on returning Json from controller.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667841/Learn-MVC-Model-view-controller-Step-by-Step-in

Comment: I need to get a JSON string before returning it.